# WebApi Controller model serialization issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, datacontractserializer

I'm facing little stranger issue with Web API controller. I have a collection which is being passed in an action of api controller. Object being used is collection is having 4 properties.

My action is able to accept collection parameter when it's properties are in specific order. See below :-

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ForexRates UpdateRates([FromBody] Rates rates)
    {
        // TODO: Obviously code :) 
        return rates;
    }
```

This code is being place in API controller & calling from Postman. See below:-

```
<rates>
  <rate> 
   <id>fefef</id>
    <rate>35353.333</rate>
    <series>dfefge</series>
    <series-order>sfefefef</series-order>  
</rate></rates>
```

If I change the order of the properties I started getting null value in my action. Can some one please explain this :)

Models

```
public class Rate
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
}

public class Rates : Collection<ForexRate>
{
}
```

Comment: Please add the implementation of Rate and Rates

Comment: I have added models as well.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to control the order with which your XML is serialized. Use `XmlElementAttribute` and specify the **Order**.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455067/xml-serialization-question-order-of-elementsc)

FYI, I suppose there is no way for you to change the order of the properties, while you supply from `PostMan` to your WebApi service. You will need to follow the exact order.

If you don't wanna do that, then pass this `Xml` as a **string parameter** and then parse it inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

The default binder can have issues when the same name is used in different places during binding.

In your case you've got Rate.Rate - both class name and property name.   Try changing your class to (and corresponding xml for the post) :

```
public class Rate
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then try changing the order.

While I don't have a definitive reason why it works in one order and not another, it's likely that when it gets to the Rate(double) value it tries to create a new Rate(object) but doesn't have the correct properties (as its just a double).

A more complicated solution would be to write a specific model binder for the Rate object.

Comment: Not actually! The name of my class n property is not same. Models posted here are just dummy names of DTO classes.

Comment: Yes creating model binder is alternate solution but still before i try next, i would like to have reason of this situation.

Comment: I have created these DTO classes as Data Contracts. May be if that can help to understand .net default serialization behavior

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with the DataContractSerializer which expects the elements to occur in a specific order (alphabetical with some consideration given to inheritance). That's the default serializer used when creating a Web API project.

You can override this and specify a different serializer during API Configuration like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter
  .SetSerializer<SomeType>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType)));
```